# JSON parsing with Trino and SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: json, sqlalchemy, orm, trino

Is there a way to use [SQLAlchemy's ORM framework](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/) with a JSON column in Trino? Here's my attempt so far:

```
pip install trino[sqlalchemy]
```

(See https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client#sqlalchemy for installation details.)

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.schema import Table, Column, MetaData

engine = create_engine(...)

Base = declarative_base()

table = Table(
  'table',
  Base.metadata,
  Column('json_col', postgresql.JSON), # I have tried other JSON types: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON
  autoload_with=engine,
  extend_existing=True)

with Session(engine_prod_a_agentservice) as session:
    
  test_ids = ['abc','def']
    
  stmt = select(table).where(
        table.c.json['key1']['key2'].in_(test_ids))
    
  print(stmt)
    
  result = session.execute(stmt)
```

This does not work because the generated WHERE clause is not correct (the following code being taken from the output of `print(stmt)`):

```sql
WHERE ((table.json_col[:json_col_1]) ->> :param_1) IN (__[POSTCOMPILE_param_2])
```

In the Trino dialect of SQL I would achieve this as follows:

```sql
WHERE cast(json_extract(json_col,'$.key1.key2') as varchar) IN ('abc', 'def')
```

Is what I want to achieve possible or is the functionality just not there (yet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have self-explained, you need to use the Trino 'json_extract' method. Try something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, String

stmt = select(table).where(func.cast(func.json_extract(table.json_col, f'$.key1.key2'), String).in_(test_ids))
```

Answer (score 1):

You at least need to import the `JSON` datatype from the trino package. Delete `from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql` and try something like (do not have setup currently at hand):

```py
import sqlalchemy as sqla
from trino.sqlalchemy.datatype import JSON

metadata = sqla.MetaData()

table = Table(
  'table',
  metadata,
  sqla.Column('json_col', JSON), 
  schema="....")
```

The package's [unit test @github](https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client/blob/b7055ffceb7d58daa920e25259defa3c12a6fd22/tests/integration/test_sqlalchemy_integration.py#L385) validating the work with the JSON column.

Comment: I've tried this but I get the error `NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression`. I've looked around the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client/) and as far as I can see (which isn't very far though) the necessary functionality has not yet been developed.

Comment: @dwolfeu you can try switching to [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive#sqlalchemy). Or maybe [PyAthena](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/).

Comment: I have submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/trinodb/trino-python-client/issues/387).